# Converting Complicated SQL query to EntityFramework

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to translate a SQL stored procedure into an EF Core query, but it's proving beyond me.

The SP I'm translating looks like this:

```
select sale.[CustName] as [Customer Name],
    cust.City,
    Max(sale.Price) as [MaxPrice],
    Avg(sale.Price) as [Average],
    sum(case when sale.Price > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as [NumDays]
from SalesRecords as sale
    inner join Customers as cust on sale.Acct = cust.AcctNbr
where sale.[Date] between /*Start Date Param*/ and /*End Date Param*/
group by cust.[CustName], cust.City
```

After some heavy Googling, I've come up with the following EF Query so far:

```
SalesDataModel salesData =
     (from s in Sales
      where s.Date >= start && s.Date <= end
      join c in Customers on s.Acct equals c.AcctNbr
      group s by new { s.Name, c.City } into cg
      select new SalesDataModel { 
         CustName = cg.GetType().Name,
         City = cg.GetType().City
         MaxBorrowed = (from sa in Sales
                        select sa.Price).Max(),
         Average = (from sa in Sales
                    select sa.Price).Average(),
         NumDays = (from sa in Sales
                    where sa.Price > 0
                    select sa.Price).Count()
         }).ToListAsync();
```

...so I think I'm on the right track. So far, I have two questions:

1. After I group my two datasets into cg, how do I select values from the group to populate SalesDataModel? cg.GetType() doesn't seem to be the way, since the "City" item in my "cust" model isn't found there.
2. Am I doing my subqueries right? They should be selecting by account number, not from the whole dataset. If I'm not correct, where am I going wrong?

Comment: You should use navigation properties, not join. Also, where does `loc` come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simple `GroupBy` query:

```cs
var query =
    from s in Sales
    where s.Date >= start && s.Date <= end
    join c in Customers on s.Acct equals c.AcctNbr
    group s by new { s.Name, c.City } into g
    select new SalesDataModel 
    { 
        CustName = g.Key.Name,
        City = g.Key.City,
        MaxBorrowed = g.Max(x => x.Price),
        Average = g.Average(x => x.Price),
        NumDays = g.Sum(x = > .Price > 0 ? 1 : 0)
    };
```